# Binding an Image in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, data-binding

I wanna show an image in WPF that is created by a process,
e.g : we have a method that is named createWPFImage()

```
Image createWPFImage() { ... }
```

So, the output of createWPFImage() is an Image.
In the XAML code, we have a something like below :

```
<StackPanel.ToolTip>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Width="64" Height="64" Margin="0 2 4 0" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel.ToolTip>
```

Now, How can I bind the output of createWPFImage() to the Image in XAML code ?
I would be appreciate if you guide me.

Comment: What do you mean by "binding" to a method? In WPF, "binding" means changing the target value when the source value changes (or vice-versa; except for one-time binding). Or you just want to "set" the output of method as Image? Is the method returning different output based on different conditions? Have you tried using a dependency property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you have class "MyClass" with method "CreateWpfImage" (see example below).

In your XAML you can create MyClass, and then call CreateWpfImage, using ObjectDataProvider in a Resources section (See Bea Stollnitz blog article [ObjectDataProvider](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=22)).

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="MyApplicationNamespace.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:MyApplicationNamespace="clr-namespace:MyApplicationNamespace"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">       

<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type MyApplicationNamespace:MyClass}" x:Key="MyClass" />
    <ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{StaticResource MyClass}" MethodName="CreateWpfImpage" x:Key="MyImage" />
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <Image Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyImage}, Path=Source}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Example MyClass code to create an image for the XAML to use -

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace MyApplicationNamespace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public Image CreateWpfImpage()
        {
            GeometryDrawing aGeometryDrawing = new GeometryDrawing();
            aGeometryDrawing.Geometry = new EllipseGeometry(new Point(50, 50), 50, 50);
            aGeometryDrawing.Pen = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 10);
            aGeometryDrawing.Brush = Brushes.Blue;
            DrawingImage geometryImage = new DrawingImage(aGeometryDrawing);

            Image anImage = new Image();
            anImage.Source = geometryImage;
            return anImage;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ObjectDataProvider is Static, but I'm gonna do it Dynamic !

Answer (score 3):

If you have a path to your image and just want to be able to change the image on the fly, then bind to a dependency property of type string and in your method, set the value of the dependency property.

```
<Image Source="{Binding MyImagePath}" />

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyImagePathProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyImagePath", typeof(string), typeof(ClassName), new PropertyMetadata("pack://application:,,,/YourAssembly;component//icons/icon1.png"));


    public string MyImagePath
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyImagePathhProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyImagePathProperty, value); }
    }
```