# Dynamically show a different amount (0-10) BitmapImages on a View

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a small problem designing problem:

My card tool should display 0-10 images on my view.

Sometime just three, sometimes six, sometimes all ten...

Due to MVVM I don't want to just `Controls.Add()` the images to the grids/controls content.

What is a good approach to this? One way would be having ten bitmap variables, but is there another better way?

**Edit:\**

I tried it like that:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CardImages}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" Stretch="Uniform" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

But its not working as it should.

I have SIX pictures, but the rest of the pictures arent visibilty (out of sigth). I want to show all of the pictures, so the 3 have to be about 50 % smaller in height and the other three atm not visible pictures should be shown under the shown three pictures. Hope thats clear.

How to solve that? I tried ScrollViewers, ViewBoxes and some different kind of templates / panels, but had no sucess. :(

Answer (score 2):

I would bind an ItemsControl to a public observable collection property that contains your image sources / locations / however you reference them on your view model and then template the items to display images.

```
<ItemsControl Binding="{Binding MyPublicProperty}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <Image Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyImage}, Path=Source}"/>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199447/binding-an-image-in-wpf) for binding the image.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can the ItemControl.Orientation be changed? Is it possible to make a new line after every 5 images? Guess a style is needed, isnt it?

Comment: @Jannik See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052342/itemscontrol-with-horizontal-orientation for orientation.  As far as breaking on five, you'll definitely want to start looking at styles.

Comment: To make the images wrap, consider using a `WrapPanel` instead of a `StackPanel` in the `ItemsPanelTemplate`.  It won't let you set the number of items after which to wrap, but you could set a max width on the panel and images to get that behavior.

Comment: Thank you both. Appreciate it. @Mike: Good hint. I will test that out tommorow, when I am going to get back to work. :)

Comment: Please review my updated start post. I have an upfollowing problem stated there.

Comment: @Jannik You didn't set a max width on the wrap panel.  Have you tried adding it?